# ASP.NET use local API Controller Endpoint

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, controller

I currently have two separate API Controllers in a single project. Controller B requires some functionalities covered by controller A. What I would like to achieve is to acces an endpoint from A from within B. However, I could not figure out how to get a reference to an instance of any controller, thus I cannot reference them at all. So my only options seem to be to make every method static or to call the endpoints using `localhost:{port}` as URI - but both would seem like bad practice (especially the last one).

So, how do I call the methods from controller A from within controller B?

Comment: You're in the same application. There's no need to make one controller call another through a HTTP request. If you have some logic that both controllers need, abstract it out to a separate class that both controllers can call.

Comment: You need to move logic functionality into a Service class, your controllers has to be dummy and just call to the method into a service class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Create a Common class and put your common logic inside some method like below:

```
public class Common
{
  public string CommonMethod()
  { 
    return "something";
  }
}
```

Now your both controller will look like the below:

**1.** **Let's suppose Controller B will be:**

```
public class BController : Controller
{
  Common _common=new Common();
  string result=_common.CommonMethod();
}
```

**2.** **Let's suppose Controller A will be:**

```
public class AController : Controller
{
  Common _common=new Common();
  string result=_common.CommonMethod();
}
```